# EF Count(*) on a TableFunction is extremely slower than launched by management studio

Tags: sql-server, performance, count, entity-framework-6

I'm throwing a trivial count on the result of a Table Function. and it takes over 10 seconds.
Through Sql Profiler I intercepted the query that is sent to the DB, and if I launch it through Management Stodio it takes 10 milliseconds.

```
IUnitOfWorkAsync<ScooterAccountingPreviewContext> _uow = new UnitOfWork<ScooterAccountingPreviewContext>();
IOrderedQueryable<GetProviders_Result> Query = (IOrderedQueryable<GetProviders_Result>)_uow.DbContext.GetProviders(AspNetUserID);
Int32 DataObjectCount = Query.Count();
```

This is the extrapolated query

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[GetProviders](@AspNetUserID) AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@AspNetUserID int',@AspNetUserID=0
```

let's leave out the fact that EF6 always adds useless code, and the groupby could have been easily avoided, but why are there so different results?

I would expect that the queries, once sent to the SqlServer engine, would be executed in the same way with comparable timings, but instead they have extremely different timings, cpu loads and readings

Comment: Possibly the execution plan that EF is using was compiled for a different `@AspNetUserID` value than `0` and you are getting a different (freshly compiled) plan when you run it in SSMS (parameter sniffing)

Comment: Speculation: The query essentially says, call GetProviders to retrieve a collection of rows, and count them as they come in. This could require GetProviders to actually retrieve all of the data, only to be thrown away.  However, if GetProviders is a table-returning, single-statement query, the optimizer can see through the function wrapper and merge that query into the outer one. At that point, it may recognize that the retrieved data is unused and only the count is needed.  I'm guessing that optimization occurred for your SSMS run but the for the EF execution. Not sure why.

Comment: ... Still 10 seconds is a super long time for a query to run. Perhaps there is something else going on like lock contention, a massive table scan. If an open transaction were active via one connection and this query were attempting to access the same rows from another (perhaps eve  from the same application), you can see delays. Perhaps an outright deadlock. It could also be the case where the query is hugely inefficient, but on the second run, most of teh required data is cached in memory.